# subView not animating properly when main View shrinks

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, subview, autoresizingmask

My app has a UIView called stepView that needs to grow and shrink, always expanding down and to the right, and always shrinking up and to the left. It has a subview, durationLabel, which runs along the entire width of the stepView and has a fixed height.

When the stepView is animated to grow larger, the label grows properly along with it: the text and the label's background slide to the right in sync with the growing stepView. However, when the stepView is animated to grow smaller, it immediately snaps to its new size, leaving a gap between the stepView's shrinking right edge and its right edge until the animation completes.

The label initialization code in stepView.m:

```
CGRect duration_frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, HEADER_HEIGHT);
self.durationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:duration_frame];
[self.durationLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self addSubview:self.durationLabel];
```

And the animation code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIM_DURATION
     animations:^{
         [stepView setFrame:newFrame]; 
     }
];
```

Using bounds/center instead of frame produces the same effect. I've considered using a transform instead, but the code for calculating "newFrame" is somewhat involved, so I'd rather avoid rewriting it if possible. I've also tried manually changing the label's frame in the same animation block, but that simply makes it disappear entirely (possibly because I was trying to animate both a view's frame and its subview's frame in the same animation block?). I've also confirmed stepView and its subviews aren't undergoing any other animations at the same time, although there are animations happening to unrelated views in separate animation blocks.

I'm at a loss for why the label should animate perfectly when the stepView grows but fail to animate at all when it shrinks. I haven't seen anything in the documentation that indicates there would be a difference. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with UILabel - using another UIView as subview instead of an UILabel the animation works fine also when you shrink.

If I understand correctly what you need to obtain as result, however, I would suggest you to try the following:

- don't set the autoresizingMask property

  ```
  // [self.durationLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
  ```
- set the stepView clipToBounds property to YES

  ```
  self.clipToBounds = YES;
  ```

This way the UILabel frame will not change but only the part which is actually within the stepView bounds will be visible. I hope this might help.

Update: just done a quick research and found that the question is already answered here  [resize uiview with UILabel and animate it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312802/resize-uiview-with-uilabel-and-animate-it-correctly) - the answers provided seem to be aligned to what I've suggested above.

Comment: Just tried this, as well as the solution you linked (I didn't think to look for UILabel in particular, sorry about that!). Neither is working just yet: the label simply stays at its original size instead of growing. As I understand it, the trick is to manually change the frame of the container view along with the frame of the stepView, without relying on autoResizing at all? (I don't think I've fully explored this solution, but of course after promising me a few hours to test I've been told to put out some fires instead, but I'll get to as soon as I can!)

Comment: Just to mention, I also tried making the label as wide as the maximum stepView width and making sure stepView.clipstoBounds = YES. Strangely, the label initially appears correctly, and grows properly, but when the stepView shrinks the label's full width becomes visible, exceeding the stepView's frame even though stepView's clipsToBounds is still YES. I'm going to try to poke at this more this weekend...